# I cannot locate my spelling/punctuation errors. My code runs fine, yet there is something wrong

Tags: java, punctuation, spelling

I wrote out a program in Java that allows the user to name certain sports based on the number of players and vice versa using a scanner. I ran it with almost every combination I could think of, and it works fine. After submitting as a class project for grading, the automated online compiler we are supposed to use returned with 2 errors. The professor tells me that there should be something wrong with my spelling/punctuation, but I cannot pinpoint it. Can someone take a look and tell me if they find something? All help is appreciated!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SportsQuiz {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    final String PROMPT = "Enter 1 to guess a sport, 2 to guess how"
            + " many players: ";

    final int NUMOFBASKET = 5;
    final int NUMOFBASE = 9;
    final int NUMOFCURL = 4;
    final int NUMOFFOOT = 11;

    System.out.print(PROMPT);

    int promptnum = s.nextInt();

    if(promptnum == 1) {

        System.out.print("Choose number of players: ");

        int numplayers = s.nextInt();

        s.nextLine();

        if(numplayers != NUMOFBASKET && numplayers != NUMOFBASE 
                && numplayers != NUMOFCURL && numplayers != NUMOFFOOT){

            System.out.print("Invalid choice.");

        } else {

            System.out.print("Which sport has " + numplayers
                    + " players? ");

            String playsport = s.nextLine();

            if(playsport.equals("Basketball")
                    ||playsport.equals("basketball")
                    && numplayers == NUMOFBASKET) {

                System.out.print("Correct!");

            } else if(playsport.equals("Football")
                    ||playsport.equals("football") 
                    && numplayers == NUMOFFOOT) {

                System.out.print("Correct!");

            } else if(playsport.equals("Baseball")
                    ||playsport.equals("baseball")
                    && numplayers == NUMOFBASE) {

                System.out.print("Correct!");       

            } else if(playsport.equals("Curling")
                    ||playsport.equals("curling")
                    && numplayers == NUMOFCURL) {

                System.out.print("Correct!");

            } else {

                System.out.print("Incorrect");

            }

        }

    } else if(promptnum == 2) {

        System.out.print("Choose a sport: ");

        s.nextLine();

        String sport = s.nextLine();

        if(sport.equals("Basketball")||sport.equals("basketball")) {

            System.out.print("How many players are on a " + sport 
                    + " team? ");

            int numsportplayers = s.nextInt();

            if(numsportplayers == NUMOFBASKET){

                System.out.print("Correct!");

            } else {

                System.out.print("Incorrect!");

            }



        } else if(sport.equals("Baseball")||sport.equals("baseball")) {

            System.out.print("How many players are on a " + sport 
                    + " team? ");

            int numsportplayers = s.nextInt();

            if(numsportplayers == NUMOFBASE){

                System.out.print("Correct!");

            } else {

                System.out.print("Incorrect!");

            }

        } else if(sport.equals("Football")||sport.equals("football")) {

            System.out.print("How many players are on a " + sport 
                    + " team? ");

            int numsportplayers = s.nextInt();

            if(numsportplayers == NUMOFFOOT){

                System.out.print("Correct!");

            } else {

                System.out.print("Incorrect!");

            }

        } else if (sport.equals("Curling")||sport.equals("curling")) {

            System.out.print("How many players are on a " + sport 
                    + " team? ");

            int numsportplayers = s.nextInt();

            if(numsportplayers == NUMOFCURL){

                System.out.print("Correct!");

            } else {

                System.out.print("Incorrect!");
            }

        } else {

            System.out.print("Invalid Choice.");

        }

    } else {

        System.out.print("Invalid Choice.");

    }

  }

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What errors where returned to you? Are you sure they weren't warnings?

Comment: Never mind; I found the mistake. Apparently, I forgot the exclamation mark that's supposed to come after "Incorrect". The online compiler assumed that to be a misspelling and returned errors. I fixed it up, and it works perfectly now. Thanks anyway, though!

Comment: but that doesn't create an error :/  , works perfectly in my Eclipse

Comment: I know. It shouldn't. The thing is, the project was very specific when it comes to the responses I was supposed to return for each input the users enters. Therefore the online compiler looked specifically for that stuff.

Comment: Syntatically there aren't any errors.  If there were errors specific to the specs of your assignment, then we wouldn't know about them unless you shared them.  I get the feeling that this question is way too localized.

Comment: I'm pretty sure "online compiler" is actually an online system that compiles the code and runs it against a test-suite. It's not a compilation error. The code runs fine. It's just that the output does not match the test-case output 100% in the 2 cases described below.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. It's more of a "tester" than a compiler. My mistake. This is just my first ComSci programming class, so I'm not really that experienced with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one instance you have "Incorrect" without an exclamation mark.

Also, in one instance you have "Invalid choice." but in another you have "Invalid Choice." (with capital C).

I'm guessing these are the two errors.

Comment: You are correct! I figured it out about a minute after I posted the question. Thanks, though. I can't believe you found it out this fast.